# Weibo redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: android, sdk, weibo, sinaweibo

I'm having trouble setting up sina weibo for a chinese app. Since I don't understand chinese I'm using google translate, and I'm sure I didn't set something properly and I get a redirect_uri_mismatch.

My redirect uri is public static final String REDIRECT_URL = "http://qhtv.argon.com/download";

And this is how I init the weibo sdk:

```
mWeibo = Weibo.getInstance(ConstantS.APP_KEY, ConstantS.REDIRECT_URL, ConstantS.SCOPE);
                           mWeibo.anthorize(mContext, new AuthDialogListener());
                           ininWeiboSDK();
                           regWeibo();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it wasn't anything from the code, just needed to set the callback uri properly on the website accesing this link: http://open.weibo.com/apps/[id]/info/advanced. Google translate didn't help me much

Answer (score 0):

In case, you don't have backend you can use default redirect URL:

```
REDIRECT_URL = https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/default.html
```

Set it in `AuthInfo`

```
AuthInfo(activity, API_KEY, REDIRECT_URL, SCOPE)
```

And don't forget to add it in Weibo console OAuth section
https://open.weibo.com/apps/1275139015/info/advanced